# Linux Subsystem for Windows

Tags: linux, windows, virtual-machine, windows-subsystem-for-linux

There is Windows subsytem for Linux and... Is there Linux subsystem for Windows? That allows you to access Windows terminal on Linux like on Windows subsytem for Linux.

The Windows Subsystem for Linux lets developers run a GNU/Linux environment -- including most command-line tools, utilities, and applications -- directly on Windows, unmodified, without the overhead of a traditional virtual machine or dualboot setup.
You can:
Choose your favorite GNU/Linux distributions from the Microsoft Store.
Run common command-line tools such as grep, sed, awk, or other ELF-64 binaries.
Run Bash shell scripts and GNU/Linux command-line applications including:
Tools: vim, emacs, tmux
Languages: NodeJS, Javascript, Python, Ruby, C/C++, C# & F#, Rust, Go, etc.
Services: SSHD, MySQL, Apache, lighttpd, MongoDB, PostgreSQL.
Install additional software using your own GNU/Linux distribution package manager.
Invoke Windows applications using a Unix-like command-line shell.
Invoke GNU/Linux applications on Windows.

Comment: What is a "windows terminal"?  If you mean powershell then yes you can install it on linux.

Comment: I know but I want to access it like WSL. If you don’t know what WSL is, check the link at bottom of question.

Comment: Define "Access it like WSL"

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what your requirements are. Do you just want to be able to run powershell scripts on a Linux machine? Do you want to have powershell as your default shell? Do you want to use Windows-specific features and somehow interact with the installed Windows system from a Linux environment on a dual boot machine? Please assume that we do know what WSL is, but we don't know what _you_ think it is/does or what you require from it. So don't tell us again to look at WSL, instead explain what you need.

Comment: As I said I just want to access Windows virtual machine that works at background just like in WSL.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain. Don't repeat the same thing, explain what kind of "access", explain what virtual machine. Most of the things that WSL brings to Windows are already natively supported (you can trivially mount Windows volumes on a Linux system for instance), so we need to know exactly what kind of access you are thinking about. Try giving an example of something you would like to be able to do.

Comment: Good grief. Chances are most people here know what WSL is to a far greater level of detail than you. Certainly more than in that very basic page you link to. We don't need to be told what WSL is, we need to understand what _you_ think it is, what _you_ are trying to do. The simple answer is "no, there is no Linux subsystem for Windows". But since that won't be a useful answer to you, if you explain what parts of WSL you are trying to replicate we might be able to help. If you don't want to tell us what you need, then we won't be able to give you a helpful answer.

Comment: I’m just asking is there a WSL-like working software that for Linux and runs Windows instead of Ubuntu, Kali, SuSe, Debian etc?

Comment: Since most of us don't know anything about Windows, we can't be expected to know what you would want to do with this hypothetical system. As Jesse already said, Powershell is already available in Linux. If you want to run other Windows software, why not run a Windows system? WSL was created to make Windows more sexy for developers. There is IMHO no need to do the opposite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No that isn't possible.

If you want to have a fully or even partially functioning windows environment on your linux machine you need either dual boot or a virtual machine.

If you are only looking for one or a few particular applications you could use [wine](http://www.winehq.org/).

"Windows terminal" is what confused me about your question because that isn't really a thing, or at least not an easily defined thing, but again if you are just looking for powershell that can be installed natively on linux.

Additionally there are virtually an unlimited number of ways to access your wsl instance on windows so saying "access like wsl" isn't really a useful description.  I can ssh to my wsl instance so you could install a windows virtual machine on your linux box and ssh to it and that is "like wsl", alternatively I normally access my wsl instance by simply typing "ubuntu" in the command line so you could create an alias on your linux machine to run windows when you type "ubuntu" but that probably wouldn't make much sense...

Answer (score 2):

WSL is not just "a way to access Linux terminal on Windows". It goes a bit deeper: it provides a Linux-compatible programming API on top of the Windows kernel, allowing you to run Linux userspace programs on Windows.

Since Linux's unix-style programming API relies on things like terminals, WSL needs to provide them too.

The opposite - providing a Windows programming API and the equivalents to some necessary bits of Windows infrastructure on Linux - sort of already exists, and has in fact existed for longer than WSL. [It's called Wine](https://www.winehq.org/), and your Linux distribution might already include a pre-packaged version of it.

You can run `wine cmd` on Linux to run the Windows command shell in a Linux terminal window. (Compared to a Windows command prompt window, a Linux terminal window is usually an upgrade.)

However, because Windows is not an open-source OS, not all of its API is published. As a result, some parts of Wine rely on reverse-engineering and might not work perfectly. There may also licensing questions: depending on your jurisdiction, you might not be authorized to run Microsoft applications on a non-Microsoft OS.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is no. You can, however, install powershellcore and .NET core in linux which is the next bext thing.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-linux

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/