# WSL equivalent for Linux

Tags: virtual-machine, windows-subsystem-for-linux

It was a mere wsl command to import a Fedora cloud image to my Windows 10.

What is the equivalent of this when I use Linux as the base OS? VirtualBox is more difficult.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linux Subsystem for Windows](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/627821/linux-subsystem-for-windows)

Comment: No. I'd like to install other Linux distributions at ease.

Comment: Do you mean you have a linux host and want to install other linux guests on it without a full-blown virtual machine?

Comment: Yes, that's what I have in mind.

Comment: Just do a `docker run -it fedora`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For another option on your Linux hosts, I would recommend Docker.  Once you [install Docker](https://docs.docker.com/get-docker/), you can quickly spin up new "containers" based on existing "images", similar to what you are doing with `wsl --import` and `wsl -d <DistroName>` with WSL on Windows.

Docker actually goes far beyond just OS images, since you can download and run many different applications/servers/programming languages with ease.

For instance:

```
docker pull opensuse/leap # pulls the latest image from the online Docker repository.
# ^^^ Not strictly necessary since the next command will load it from the repo if it isn't found locally
docker run -td --name opensuse opensuse/leap # Starts a container from the image running in daemon mode with a terminal
docker exec -it opensuse bash # Executes bash inside the running container with an interactive terminal

# Exit bash the image (CTRL+D)

# Cleanup
docker stop opensuse # Stops the container
docker rm opensuse # Removes the container
docker rmi opensuse/leap # Removes the image
```

One thing you need to be well aware of is that these containers themselves are always ephemeral.  Any changes made to a container or files created in them **will be lost** when the container is stopped.  To persist configuration, you create `Dockerfile`s.  To persist files, you mount an external volume (which can be a directory on your host) when starting the container.

There's definitely some learning curve in figuring out the Docker options needed for your particular use-case, but once you get the basics down (such as those commands above), it's very easy to try out different images easily.

Bonus - You can install Docker into a WSL2 instance and have those benefits there as well.  You'll find a *lot* of Docker images for things that you just can't load under WSL, even.

Answer (score 5):

Now that I understand you aren't looking for a [Linux Subsystem for Windows](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/627821/linux-subsystem-for-windows), but rather a way to run several linux guests on a linux host.  There are several ways to do this including:  Virtual machines, containers, chroot

You've indicated that you don't like virtual machines, and I don't know much about containers, but here's how to chroot:

When you use `chroot` you are changing your root directory to another directory on your host system.  So you you `chroot /var/chroot/ubuntu`, then `/var/chroot/ubuntu/bin` will become your new `/bin`.  This means when you run `/bin/bash`, you are running Ubuntu's version of bash.  If you run `/usr/bin/apt install <package>` you are installing Ubuntu's version of  to that chroot.

You can set up a `chroot` for most distros.  Different distros have different way to set this up so you'll need to consult documentation for your distro of interest.  For Debian-based distros I use `debootstrap` to install the systems like so:

```
debootstrap buster /var/chroot/buster http://ftp.debian.org/debian
debootstrap wheezy /var/chroot/wheezy http://archive.debian.org/debian
debootstrap hardy /var/chroot/hardy http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
debootstrap kali-rolling /var/chroot/kali http://http.kali.org/kali
```

More complete information here: https://wiki.debian.org/chroot